# Using ADSI To Open A Newly Created AD LDS Instance

Tags: active-directory, adsi

I created a new instance using Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services Setup Wizard with the distinguished name of `CN=MyName,DC=MyComponent` successfully. I see the instance as a running windows service. Within ADSI, anytime I try to connect to that Distinguish Name I get:

> Operation failed.  Error code 0x202b A referral was returned from the
>   server.  data 0, 1 access point

My path is:  `LDAP://CN=MyName,DC=MyComponent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to add the port:

LDAP://localhost:389/CN=MyName,DC=MyComponent

Works from there.

Comment: Put our question as answered please.

Comment: You have to wait a couple days before SO allows you to answer your own question.